# Python3.x: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Tags: excel, python-3.x, operating-system, xlwt

I have numerous text files in one folder. Each text file has two values that are written in separate lines (using \n\ in .write function). It looks like the following.

```
0.907831
0.992549
```

I want to create one master excel file that has all of the values in my text files combined (rather than manually entering them).

The desired output would look like the following.

```
'Filename' 0.907831 0.992549
```

So far, I have the following code.

```
import xlwt
import os
import fnmatch

path='Z:\Data\13-output'
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('data')
row = 0


for files in os.walk(path):
     for file in files:
         if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
             L = open(os.path.join( file), "r").read()
             sheet.write(row,5,L)
             row += 1

wbk.save('all_values_in_txt.xls')
```

It is currently running into the following error (below). Any idea on how I can improve/fix the code?

```
  File "<ipython-input-81-ddeb0284f378>", line 17, in <module>
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):

  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda3\lib\fnmatch.py", line 34, in fnmatch
    name = os.path.normcase(name)

  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 48, in normcase
    s = os.fspath(s)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.walk` returns a list of 3-item tuples, so you need to unpack the tuples when you iterate over the list:

```
for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
     for file in files:
         if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
             L = open(os.path.join(root, file), "r").read()
             sheet.write(row,5,L)
             row += 1
```

Please read [`os.walk`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) for more details.